# django specific settings app

Tags: django, django-apps

I am working on a django app that needs a directory to download and store files.

I want to keep my app reusable so I do not want to hard code the path of this directory.
So I want to make this path a setting/a global variable that can be set up.

Where could I put this setting/global variable?

Is this kind of approach good ?
http://blog.muhuk.com/2010/01/26/developing-reusable-django-apps-app-settings.html

Thanks for your advice!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Great first question.

Comment: Broken link at muhuk.com.

Comment: link still doesn't work, but google's cache helps out: http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:mNs3to1345cJ:blog.muhuk.com/2010/01/26/developing-reusable-django-apps-app-settings.html+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=de#.UntjOmTuJII

Comment: This is the [new location](http://blog.muhuk.com/2010/01/26/developing-reusable-django-apps-app-settings.html) of the link.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I use the following methodology:

```
# some file in your app:

from django.conf import settings

MY_APP_SETTING = getattr(settings, 'MY_APP_SETTING', 'some default value')
```

This effectively allows end-users to customized the setting in their own settings.py, but still ensures that there's always some default value set. You can now use `MY_APP_SETTING` at will in the rest of your code.

**UPDATE**

The link in your question was taking too long to load, so I just went ahead and answered. As it turns out, the method I suggested is the same as what it suggests, so yes, I'd consider that approach good ;).

Comment: Sad part is that it won't make sense if the said setting can't have any default value (an API key, for instance)